# Unable to instantiate an object of XSSFWorkbook in Java servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xssf

I'm trying to work with XSSFWorkbook in my web application. I ran a sample application with XSSFWorkbook as a plain Java program (with `public static void main(String args[])`) - it runs fine - an excel sheet is generated.

However, when I run the same piece of code in my java based web application - an instance of XSSFWorkbook is not instantiated. No Exception is thrown either!

Please help!

Comment: Please add you code.

Answer (score 0):

```
the below code works perfectly fine for me

public void trackerUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    UploadedFile tracker = event.getUploadedFile();
    XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    InputStream stream = tracker.getInputStream();
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);  
}
Here, the listener is called from my xhtml page.
```

Comment: Hi yusuf,  I had done in the same way you had done. Kindly specify the jars you had used and i am using maven project.

Comment: I have used apache-poi API.

Comment: hi, i am using the same jar but still i am getting that error